# SyndicationFeed content:encoded

Tags: c#, rss

I’m using the `SyndicationFeed` class to consume some rss feeds.  I am wondering how to get the `content:encoded` node of an RSS feed.  This is the code I’m using:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream());

SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
{
     string title = (item.Title != null) ? item.Title.Text : String.Empty;

     string content = ??

     string pubDate = (item.PublishDate != null) ? item.PublishDate.ToString("r") : String.Empty;

}
```

I can use `item.Summary.Text` but that seems to return the `Description` node, which can be just a short summary, while `content:encoded` will have the full content.  There’s an option for `item.content`, but I'm not sure how to use it and documentation is scarce.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (SyndicationElementExtension extension in item.ElementExtensions)
    {
         XElement ele = extension.GetObject<XElement>();
         if (ele.Name.LocalName == "encoded" && ele.Name.Namespace.ToString().Contains("content"))
         {
              sb.Append(ele.Value + "<br/>");
         }
    }
```

Comment: Beware the HTML injection in this post... Still a useful answer.

Comment: yes, worked great. again, not sure why the <br /> needs to be added, but I guess it can serve as an example of sorts