# Getting the <content:encoded> using rss feed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

```
  private void UpdateFeedList(string feedXML)
    {
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(feedXML);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlReader);

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            feedListBox.ItemsSource = feed.Items;
        });
    }
```

this is the code that i'm using to get a feed and it works fine, I'm binding the Summary.Text to a textblock using a converter but i need to get the content some how, i searched alot and some code works but not the way i wanted so any help will be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121565/syndicationfeed-contentencoded) might be useful  to you.

Answer (score 0):

for you to show the contents inside some tags use the Regex.Match.

```
your_content = Regex.Match(Item_with_your_content, @"<img\s+src='(.+)'\s+border='0'\s+/>").Groups[1].Value,
```

this code will fetch the tag  the feed. Change to your desired tag.